# In Flutter, getting URL but not able to display video on VideoPlayer and getting Error

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation, flutter-test, flutter-video-player

I am not able to display the video in UI but I am getting URL and it showing some "Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Future already completed"

```
   List<String> videoList = [];
   
   VideoPlayerController _controller;

    @override
   void initState() {
super.initState();
getVideos(context);
  }

  @override
  Future<void> dispose() async {
  super.dispose();
  if (videoList != null && mounted) {
  await _controller.dispose();

   }
}
```

The code where I want to display the video:

```
        Container(
              height: 200.0,
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15.0, horizontal: 15.0),
              child: ListView(
                //shrinkWrap: true,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                children: [
                  FutureBuilder (
                      future: hasInitialized,
                      builder: (context, snapshot){
                        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                          return new ListView.builder(
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                              itemCount:videoList.length,
                              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,int index){
                              return Container(
                                height: 180,
                                width: 180,
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                child: _controller.value.isInitialized ?

                                    Stack(
                                      children: [
                                        VideoPlayer(_controller),
                                        _ControlsOverlay(_controller),
                                        // AspectRatioVideo(_controller),
                                      ],
                                    )
                                    :Container()
                              );
                            }
                            );
                        } else {
                          return
                            //Text("No video");
                          Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
                        }
                      }
                  )
                ],
              ),

            ),
```

The code from where I am getting the video url:

```
                Future  hasInitialized;
         Future<List<String>> getVideos(context) async {
       var document = await          FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").
         doc(auth.currentUser.uid).get();
        List<String> videos = [];
      for (var item in document.data()['videos']) {
        videos.add(item);
             }
       setState(() {
         _controller =    VideoPlayerController.network(videoList.toString());
        // _controller =  VideoPlayerController.network(videoList[videos]);
       _controller.addListener(() {
          setState(() {});
         });
       hasInitialized = _controller.initialize();
       _controller.setLooping(false);
         _controller.initialize();
        });

      videoList= videos;
     print(videoList.length);
    print(videoList);
     return videos;
      }
```

The error I am getting:

[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Future already completed
E/flutter ( 9697): #0      _AsyncCompleter.complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:45:31)
E/flutter ( 9697): #1      VideoPlayerController.initialize (package:video_player/video_player.dart:310:25)
E/flutter ( 9697): 
E/flutter ( 9697):
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 9697): Playback error
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 9697):   com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Source error
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 9697):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:554)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 9697):       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 9697):       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 9697):       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 9697):   Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.FileDataSource$FileDataSourceException: com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.FileDataSource$FileDataSourceException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: []: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 9697):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.FileDataSource.open(FileDataSource.java:97)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 9697):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultDataSource.open(DefaultDataSource.java:199)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 9697):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.StatsDataSource.open(StatsDataSource.java:84)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 9697):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ProgressiveMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ProgressiveMediaPeriod.java:1013)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 9697):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:415)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 9697):       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 9697):       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 9697):       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 9697):   Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.FileDataSource$FileDataSourceException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: []: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 9697):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.FileDataSource.openLocalFile(FileDataSource.java:166)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 9697):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.FileDataSource.open(FileDataSource.java:89)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 9697):       ... 7 more
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 9697):   Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: []: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 9697):       at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:492)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 9697):       at java.io.RandomAccessFile.(RandomAccessFile.java:289)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 9697):       at java.io.RandomAccessFile.(RandomAccessFile.java:152)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 9697):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.FileDataSource.openLocalFile(FileDataSource.java:155)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 9697):       ... 8 more
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 9697):   Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 9697):       at libcore.io.Linux.open(Native Method)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 9697):       at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:166)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 9697):       at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:254)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 9697):       at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:166)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 9697):       at android.app.ActivityThread$AndroidOs.open(ActivityThread.java:7542)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 9697):       at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:478)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 9697):       ... 11 more
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 9697): Playback error

Answer (score 0):

`_controller.initialize();` returns a Future i guess.
You are calling it twice:

```
hasInitialized = _controller.initialize();
_controller.setLooping(false);
_controller.initialize();
```

That's why you are getting: `Future already completed`

Comment: deleted, still no difference.